# Search youtube api based on viewcount

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to find a way to query the youtube api based on viewcount but reversed. For example get a list of videos for a channel with least views or videos for a keyword with 0 views. I read the api documentation and so far no luck. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. :(

Although you can do a search with order by viewcount, the resources are sorted from highest to lowest number of views.

You'd have to cycle through the page tokens until the end to get the ones with the lowest viewCount.

It's a bit of a pain, but possible.